# How to make scrollbar disappear when not needed?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to set up a responsive site for multiple sized screens, e.g. Bootstrap sizes `xs`, `sm`, `md`, and `lg`.

Everything works fine on the three smaller sizes, i.e. the scrollbar is only present on the right side when it is needed.

However, on the **large size screen**, which has a 1024px width so that it doesn't get too wide, **how can I get the vertical scrollbar to only appear when it is needed?**

**SMALLER SIZES OK:**
[image]

**LARGE SIZE has unnecessary scrollbar when not needed:** 
[image]

```css
.pagecontent {
  margin: 0 18px;
}
/* bootstrap override */

.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}
.navbar {
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.navbar-text {
  float: left !important;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.navbar-right {
  float: right!important;
}
.navbar-nav>li>a {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.navbar-nav {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}
.container {
  width: 1024px;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
html {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* make sure it is at least as tall as the viewport */
  position: relative;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  /* force the BODY element to match the height of the HTML element */
  background-color: #999;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="?">Bootstrap Showcase</a>
        </div>

      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="pagecontent">

      <div>this is a test line</div>
      <div>this is a test line</div>
      <div>this is a test line</div>
      <div>this is a test line</div>
      <div>this is a test line</div>
      <div>this is a test line</div>
      <div>this is a test line</div>
      <div>this is a test line</div>
      <div>this is a test line</div>
      <div>this is a test line</div>
      <div>this is a test line</div>
      <div>this is a test line</div>
      <div>this is a test line</div>
      <div>this is a test line</div>
      <div>this is a test line</div>
      <div>this is a test line</div>
      <div>this is a test line</div>
      <div>this is a test line</div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**ADDENDUM:**

If I remove `overflow-y: scroll`, I get the scrollbar on the right, but the content then extends before the bottom:

[image]

Comment: So your screenshot isn't quite what's produced by the code you gave us.... Is there a reason you're using this wrapper instead of using something like `padding` on `body` and leaving the wrapper in-flow?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `overflow-y: auto;` CSS attribute. it then only shows the scrollbar when required

Comment: Leaving my +1 here since this solved the (original) question as asked, but doesn't actually solve the problem, since someone _cough_ didn't provide enough code to make us realize there was more to this problem.

Comment: Exactly, that's why I marked this answer as correct and asked a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37167577/how-to-get-text-from-scrolling-off-bottom-of-container-yet-keep-scroll-bar-on-f

Answer (score 0):

Remove  `overflow-y: scroll;` from `.container`in the css. And why do you have the `container` class listed twice in the CSS?

Comment: If he removes it, he won't have one when he wants one

Comment: Why not? The browser will include the scroll if it goes past the page.

Comment: I've done things like that before. CSS reusable snippets (for example, the engine of a CSS Accordion) and boilerplates oft get this treatment, rather than being mingled with the visual styling. However, this case it might just be from "embedding" external style sheets.

Comment: Because removing it would remove it on the smaller devices, he needs it to show automatically on element overflow for different sized screens, which would justify the `auto` part.

Comment: Rachel, I posted a screenshot in my post above of what happens when I remove it. I would actually like to have the scrollbar on the right side like that but it messes up the content which extends pass the bottom as in screenshot.

Comment: @EdwardTanguay gotcha I just assumed the container was the entire page.

Comment: @RhysO right but wrong reason. Removing it reverts `overflow` to the default of `visible`. Since the parent has a "fixed" size (the code doesn't indicate, though), it overflows outside of the `.container`.

Comment: Does anyone know if there is a way to have the scrollbar on the far right as when I remove `overflow-y: scroll;` yet not have my text overflow through the bottom of my `.container`?

Comment: @abluejelly Ah I see now, I knew it would cut off the bottom, but I didn't realise it would default to visible.

Comment: @EdwardTanguay Refresh the page and check the other answer, RhysO already posted it :)

Comment: @RhysO Yeah the `auto` behavior seems like it would be default, but it's not. Reason being you usually want your elements to stretch instead of switch to a scrollbar. `visible` is actually kinda sane of a choice from the browser's pov.

Comment: @abluejelly, yet RhysO's answer with `auto` is a good solution, but when the scrollbar is visible, it is on the right side of the container instead of on the right side of the browser. It would be better if the scroll bar were on the right side of the browser, otherwise the mouse wheel doesn't work in the gray areas which is an unnecessarily awkward browser experience for the user.

Comment: @EdwardTanguay Little very late response, but... The browser window only has one scroll bar. If you want your scrolling content to use it, you'll have to use `position:fixed` and make sure your content-wrapper has proper margin top and bottom sizes. The problem is then the classic always-visible header & footer problem, and `overflow:visible` is your friend once more.