# How to get text from scrolling off bottom of container, yet keep scroll bar on far right of browser?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I get the following site to work so that if the text is longer than the container, (1) the **text does not scroll off the bottom**, and (2) the **scrollbar is on the right side of the browser** and not on the right side of the container?

(The reason I want the scrollbar on the right side of the browser is because if it is on the right side of the container, then the mouse-wheel does not work when the cursor in on the gray area, which is a disconcerting user experience.)

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>         
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>     
        <style type="text/css">      

            .pagecontent {
                margin: 0 18px;
            }

            /* bootstrap override */
            .container {
                width: 100%;
                padding: 0;
            }
            .navbar {
                border-radius: 0px;
            }

            .navbar-text {
                float: left !important;
                margin-right: 10px;
            }
            .navbar-right {
                float: right!important;
            }

            .navbar-nav>li>a {
                padding-top: 15px;

                padding-bottom: 15px;
            }

            .navbar-nav {
                margin-bottom: 0;
                margin-top: 0;
                margin-left: 0;
            }


            /* viewport lg */
            @media (min-width: 1200px) {
                .container {
                    width: 1024px;
                    padding: 0;
                    background-color: #fff;
                    position:absolute;
                    top:0;
                    bottom:0;
                    left:0;
                    right:0;

                    /* overflow-y: auto; TEXT DOESN'T EXTEND OFF BOTTOM (GOOD), BUT SCROLL BAR IS ON CONTAINER NOT ON RIGHT OF BROWSER (BAD)*/
                }
                html{
                    min-height:100%;/* make sure it is at least as tall as the viewport */
                    position:relative;
                }
                body{
                    height:100%; /* force the BODY element to match the height of the HTML element */
                    background-color: #999;
                    /* overflow-y: auto; SCROLLBAR ON RIGHT OF BROWSER (GOOD) BUT TEXT EXTENDS OFF BOTTOM (BAD) */
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="?">Bootstrap Showcase</a>
                    </div>                

                </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="pagecontent">

                <div>this is a test line</div>
                <div>this is a test line</div>
                <div>this is a test line</div>
                <div>this is a test line</div>
                <div>this is a test line</div>
                <div>this is a test line</div>
                <div>this is a test line</div>
                <div>this is a test line</div>
                <div>this is a test line</div>
                <div>this is a test line</div>
                <div>this is a test line</div>
                <div>this is a test line</div>
                <div>this is a test line</div>
                <div>this is a test line</div>
                <div>this is a test line</div>
                <div>this is a test line</div>
                <div>this is a test line</div>
                <div>this is a test line</div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

## ADDENDUM

If I remove `position: absolute;`, it fixes this immediate problem but then the container does not extend down to the bottom if there is not enough text, as it does correctly when there is no gray background:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position:absolute` from container.

http://codepen.io/ruchiccio/pen/VaRXKO

**EDIT: All you need to do is give the container div this style:**

```
height:100vh;
```

Comment: If I remove `position: absolute;` it fixes this immediate problem but then the container does not extend down to the bottom if there is not enough text. I added a screenshot of this above in my post.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the text you want to scroll in a `div`, then add a `overflow-y: auto;` on the div. This will add a scrollbar to the div and not to the browser window. See this simple JSFiddle for an example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rhysoc/ot869u2b/)

Comment: Right, but I don't want the scroll bar on the `div` but on the whole page. For example, when I removed `position:absolute`, I get what I want but then the container does not extend down to the bottom if there is not enough text. I added a screenshot of this above in my post. So I somehow have to get the white container to extend down to the bottom of the browser window. I've tried various combinations of `min-height: 100%` and `height:100%` on the `.container`, `html`, and `body` but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved this problem for this particular layout by taking out `position:absolute` and then adding a centered background image of white:

```
            background-color: #999;
            background-image: url('images/system/background_white_page.png');
            background-repeat: repeat-y;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-position: center; 
            background-size: 1024px 1px;
```

But while this works for this particular layout, it would not work if e.g. you had a footer which was anchored to the bottom of the page on all of the smaller viewports but on the largest could jump to the middle of the page somewhere depending on how much html content was in the `.container`.

So if anyone has a more general solution to this problem, please don't hesitate to share it.